# Shared Facet between Taxonomy and Content Field

Tags: search

My search page needs to show results from both content types and taxonomies.

Both the content type and taxonomies that I am searching on have a field called `training_location`. The `training_location` field is also a taxonomy with only two options: "Remote" and "In-Person".

Is there a way to merge a facet so that I can filter results for both a content type and taxonomy that has the `training_location` field?

To be clear, the system is currently forcing me to create a separate facet for the content type `training_location` field and a separate facet for the taxonomy `training_location` field, which is not what I want.